# Trying to get basic Nodejs example working on GAE

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, gcloud

I'm using Windows 7x64, gcloud installed version

```
Google Cloud SDK 0.9.71

app 2015.07.24
app-engine-java 1.9.24
app-engine-python 1.9.24
app-engine-python-extras 1.9.21
bq 2.0.18
bq-win 2.0.18
core 2015.07.24
core-win 2015.07.24
gcloud 2015.07.24
gsutil 4.13
gsutil-win 4.13
preview 2015.07.24
windows-ssh-tools 2015.06.02
```

I'm trying to run on preview and deploy the tutorial example from [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-getting-started/tree/1-hello-world). *Note that app.yaml from this example has "nodejs" set as runtime.*

After running command

```
gcloud preview app run --host localhost:8080 app.yaml
```

I get

```
RuntimeError: Unknown runtime 'nodejs'; supported runtimes are 'custom', 'go', 'java', 'java7', 'php', 'php55', 'python, 'python27', 'vm'.
```

If I put "vm" for runtime it wants to use docker, which doesn't work for me either and I wanted to use the option to do this [without docker](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=163) anyhow.

If I put "custom" for runtime in yaml file I get:

```
ValueError: The --custom_entrypoint flag must be set for custom runtimes
```

Example given in the help output for this switch is the following

```
--custom_entrypoint="gunicorn -b localhost:{port} mymodule:application"
```

I tried with this, best guess

```
gcloud preview app run --custom_entrypoint="nodejs -b localhost:{8080} mymodule:application" app.yaml
```

and got this

```
ERROR: Argument [--custom_entrypoint=nodejs -b localhost:{8080} mymodule:application] is not a valid deployable file.
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.run) Errors occurred while parsing the App Engine app configuration.
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I just found the [quickstart guide](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/hello-world) for Node.js. It suggests using `npm` and `node` for local development, and only using `gcloud` for deployment, which should work with the `runtime: nodejs` flag.

Comment: Hmh, OK, maybe that will work even though the last time I tried to deploy this very same example the server kept responding with 503. I shall give it a try. I wanted to get it running on preview as a local test, before getting in deployed. I figured, if it doesn't run locally, it won't run on the server either.

Comment: More yak shaving. Hangs on `Copying certificates for secure access. You may be prompted to create an SSH keypair.`

Comment: Are you by any chance on a different drive from the temporary directory? That is, does `python.exe -c 'import tempfile; print tempfile.mkdtemp()'` show a temporary file on a different drive from your current directory? If so, try moving your project to the same drive and see if you still get the same behavior.

Comment: @ZacharyNewman I'm not entirely certain I understand your question. If I input above commandline in the working directory I get `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`. My Python path is `C:\Python27` and the project is in `C:\gae\nodejs`. I doubt there's anything python related going on my other drives.

Comment: Can you open a Python prompt an run `import tempfile`, then `print tempfile.mkdtemp()`? There's a known issue that results in a hang at the same point with cross-drive paths. That said, given that you're on `C:\` the whole time, it might not be the issue. I'll dig a little more. A full, verbose log may be helpful.

Comment: @ZacharyNewman here's the output `>>> import tempfile
>>> print tempfile.mkdtemp()
c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\tmp_orac1`. Seems OK to me in regard of your previous comment. Thanks for your time, btw.

Comment: Here I reran the deploy command with verbosity set to debug -> http://pastebin.com/qsKU7Sg7 The operation simply hangs from that point forward.

Answer (score 0):

The gcloud command seems to be undergoing some changes, so this question seems no longer valid, since we're meant to run `dev_appserver.py` instead of `gcloud` to run devserver processes; you can also just straight-up run the node server, or even use docker to build the image from your dockerfile and run that as a container.

If running from dev_appserver.py, make sure you have `runtime: custom` and a Dockerfile sourcing `FROM`[`gcr.io/google_appengine/nodejs`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docker), since dev_appserver.py currently raises:

```
RuntimeError: Unknown runtime 'nodejs'; supported runtimes are 'custom', 'go', 'java', 'java-compat', 'java7', 'php55', 'python', 'python-compat', 'python27'.
```